# VB.NET to C# Sending parameters to an SQL datasource in code behind

Tags: c#, vb.net, parameters, code-behind

Being ignorant about C#, can anyone help me translate this vb code to C#. I tried many on-line converters but they are useless. Need a real expert.....I'm trying to send parameters from code behind to an SQL datasource. Any bilingual in here:

```
    Dim searchBox_par As New Parameter()

Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click


    Dim intCount As Integer
    Dim searchTxt = SearchBox.Text
    Dim arrText = Split(searchTxt)


    For intCount = 0 To UBound(arrText)

        searchBox_par.Name = "IDTextBox1"
        searchBox_par.Type = TypeCode.String
        searchBox_par.DefaultValue = arrText(intCount)

        SqlDataSource3.SelectParameters.Clear()
        SqlDataSource3.SelectParameters.Add(searchBox_par)
        GridView2.Visible = True


    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should look somthing like this.
However, note that you need to add the event handler for click on button1.
something like:

```
Button1.click += Button1_Click;
```

something else that puzzles me, is why do you clear the parameters list inside the loop?
Shouldn't it be before you start the loop?

```
Parameter searchBox_par = New Parameter();

protedted void Button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgse As) {

    Integer intCount;
    string searchTxt = SearchBox.Text;
    string[] arrText = Split(searchTxt);

    For(int intCount = 0; intCount < arrText.length; intCount++) {

        searchBox_par.Name = "IDTextBox1";
        searchBox_par.Type = TypeCode.String;
        searchBox_par.DefaultValue = arrText[intCount];

        SqlDataSource3.SelectParameters.Clear();
        SqlDataSource3.SelectParameters.Add(searchBox_par);
        GridView2.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However I'm getting the following errors: 1. the name Split doesn't exist in the current context. 2. The type Parameter couldn't be found. 3. System.Array doesn't contain a definition for length. Any help?

Comment: Sorry, translated on the fly didn't notice a few things.
1. string[] arrText = Split(searchTxt); should be string[] arrText = searchTxt.Split('');
2. type Parameter - you probably need to translate your Imports statements to Using statements. it's probably a part of System.Data namespace or something like that.
3. try Length instead of length.

Comment: Thank you. Getting closer.... The type parameter is still not found. I will publish the entire code in a minute...

Comment: that's strange. Parameter should be in System.Web.UI.WebControls.Parameter namespace, at least from what I understand. maybe it's better to try the .NET Reflector and see what it gives you.

Comment: @ Zohar Peled yes the System.Web.UI.WebControls was missing. Now the code works well.

I moved the SqlDataSource3.SelectParameters.Clear() outside the loop but it threw an error that the parameter is already declared.

Comment: Ok, that's because all the parameters you add in the loop have the same name. this means that in the code you had before taking the SqlDataSource3.SelectParameters.Clear() outside the loop the only parameter you had was named "IDTextBox1" and had the default value of arrText[arrText.Length - 1]. 

if that's the only parameter you need, then the loop is just a waist  of code and time. if not, then you need to add parameters with different names for each iteration.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using an SQL database that doesn't support free text search. Thus I'm implementing this loop to be able to search the sql database (one column only in a table). First I split the words in the SearchBox.Text and then I send each word at a time as a paramater @IDTextBox1 to the SQL select statement (with LIKE). For example if a user type 'Red Black' in the searchbox, then he'll get a result with all the rows where the column contains either Red or Black.  Maybe there is a better and faster way to accomplish this....Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, can you use stored procedures and user-defined types?
If so, I would probably create a user defined table type that contains  a single nvarchar column, create a data table in the code from the split results, and send it to a stored procedure using that type to do an inner join with the search table where the search column like the udt column. this way you get the same result but only go to the database once.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the final updated code that works well.... Thank you all for your tips!

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
namespace Identity2_0
{  
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
     protected void SearchBoxButton_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Parameter searchBox_par = new Parameter();
        string searchTxt = SearchBox.Text;
        string[] arrText = searchTxt.Split();
        searchBox_par.Name = "IDTextBox1";
        searchBox_par.Type = TypeCode.String; 
        for (int intCount = 0; intCount < arrText.Length; intCount++)
        {
            SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Clear(); 
            searchBox_par.DefaultValue = arrText[intCount];
            SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add(searchBox_par);
        }

         GridView1.Visible = true;        }
}
```

}

Comment: The 'Split' call is incorrect - use string[] arrText = searchTxt.Split(' ');

Comment: Also, as Zohar mentioned, you need the event wireup (Button1.Click += Button1_Click;)

Answer (score 0):

If you use .NET Reflector on the compiled binary, it will decompile it into C# for you.